# Azure Connection Strings

Tags: c#, azure, entity-framework

I have a .NET application running on Azure, connected to SQL database on Azure using entity framework.  Currently my connection strings contain the username and password.  I have been asked to remove the username and password information.  For our internal applications we have replaced that information with `integrated security=True`.  From what I understand I can't do that with applications running on Azure.  What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: It's been awhile since I've messed with that particular aspect of azure but I think you can set up environmental variables. There are doubtless other ways but that is straightforward

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a managed identity, and then add it to your Azure SQL Database + change your code a little bit to use an acquired token from Azure AD in order to execute commands against your SQL database.

There's a step by step in here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-access-sql